# Insert String array in JSON plain-text

Tags: java, android, json

I've created some JSON strings in Java but I don't know how to insert string array.

For example, I've want to add string the format is:

```
String aux1 = "{ \"key\" : \"value\"};
```

But if i want to add as value: `new String[] {"string1", "string2"};`

How I can represent a string array in text-plain format??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
String[] strArray = new String[] {"string1", "string2"};

JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
jo.put("key", Arrays.asList(strArray));
```

Output would be:

```
{"key":["string1","string2"]}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know these solutions, but I want to know barcoded format. Like "{\"key\" : [\"string1\", \"string2\"]}} or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Use the [JSONObject class](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) :

```
JSONObject object = new JsonObject();
object.put("key1", "value1");
object.put("key2", "value2");
String jsonString = object.toString(); //This will create the corresponding JSON-formatted string
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] strArray = new String[] {"string1", "string2"};
String str1 = Arrays.toString(strArray);
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
jobj.put("yourstringKey",str1);
```

you can do above way only if your strArray size is more(supose greater than 10.) But if your array is small.then use following way.

```
JSONObject jobj1=new JSONObject();
jobj1.put("key1","value1");
jobj1.put("key2","value2");
JSONObject jobj=new JSONObject();
jobj.put("mystring",jobj1.toStirng());
```